# Framework change causes exception: Cannot marshal '': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination ...?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

From my managed code (let's call it MyLib) I am using a library (let's call it OtherLib) that is basically a wrapper around some c++ code (I have never seen the wrapper code or have had access to its source, nor will I have it).

When my calling library is targetting the 3.5 framework all is good and dandy. When I make it target .NET 4.0 I am getting this exception when using a method from OtherLib:

Cannot marshal 'parameter #3': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (this value type must be paired with Struct).

This happens, when I am calling a method on one of the types supplied by the wrapper. On line 4 I get above stated exception.

```
            If results.Compute(coordOrg, True, Nothing) Then
                 For Each Coord As Coordinate3D In queueDest
                    resDM(fromIndex, Coord.zMeter, DistanceCostType.CrowFly) = Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(pointFrom.X - Coord.xMeterOrLongDeg, 2) + Math.Pow(pointFrom.Y - Coord.yMeterOrLatDeg, 2)) / 1000, 6)
                    resDM(fromIndex, Coord.zMeter, DistanceCostType.Road) = Math.Round(results.GetCost(Coord, m_itiDistance) / 100000, 6)
                    resDM(fromIndex, Coord.zMeter, DistanceCostType.Time) = Math.Round(results.GetCost(Coord, m_itiTime) / 100 / 60, 4)
                Next
            End If
```

Has anyone encountered something similar ?

EDIT:
I have tried switching the targetting from 3.5 to 4.0 and back again. Under 3.5 all work fine under 4.0 it throws this exception.
I have tried creating a wrapper project targetting 3.5, exposing a static class retrieving results from the OtherLib. Again when I call it from project compiled to 4.0 it fails and works when compiled for 3.5

EDIT2: Enum definition

```
Public Enum DistanceCostType
    CrowFly
    Road
    Time
End Enum
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of DistanceCostType? Ultimately, without access to the definition of the unmanaged type definitions, it may be difficult or impossible to determine the problem without guessing.

Answer (score 2):

:)  It seems there aren’t many people who’ve run into this specific problem, but I’m one of them! My OpenCL bindings have this issue, and I don’t know to resolve it. Did anyone manage to get a fix or further information on this issue?

Here are the P/Invoke definitions (the last parameter is the problem). There is also a detailed discussion with a way to reproduce the problem in the "Discussions" tab at openclnet.codeplex.com (under "New test for you").

Cl.Event is a structure with a single IntPtr member.

http://openclnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/77409#1251581 (look for "struct Event").

1. The one below works for .NET 4.0 but not for version below it with the error (Cannot marshal 'parameter #9': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Int/UInt must be paired with SysInt or SysUInt))

   ```
   [DllImport(Library)]
   private static extern ErrorCode clEnqueueWriteBuffer(IntPtr commandQueue,
                                                        IntPtr buffer,
                                                        Bool blockingWrite,
                                                        IntPtr offset,
                                                        IntPtr cb,
                                                        IntPtr ptr,
                                                        uint numEventsInWaitList,
                                                        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.SysUInt, SizeParamIndex = 6)] Event[] eventWaitList,
                                                        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] out Event e);
   ```
2. This one works on .NET 3.5 and below, but fails on .NET 4.0 with the error (Cannot marshal 'parameter #9': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Int/UInt must be paired with Struct))

   ```
   [DllImport(Library)]
   private static extern ErrorCode clEnqueueWriteBuffer(IntPtr commandQueue,
                                                        IntPtr buffer,
                                                        Bool blockingWrite,
                                                        IntPtr offset,
                                                        IntPtr cb,
                                                        IntPtr ptr,
                                                        uint numEventsInWaitList,
                                                        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.SysUInt, SizeParamIndex = 6)] Event[] eventWaitList,
                                                        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)] out Event e);
   ```

Comment: Well I still don't know the answer by any chance. I worked around it in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

Until Framework 4, it was somewhat an oddity that structs containing only one field of type IntPtr or int couldn't be marshaled as Struct.